# Rename a file in subversion while commiting

Tags: svn

I have a requirement. I want an automation while committing a file in SVN.It's like while committing that particular file it will trigger a script and that script will rename that committed file with version number of that file.

For example, if I am committing a file `test.js(version:201)` in a particular location in SVN, after commit it will be renamed automatically as `test_versionnumber.js(test_201.js)`. Please help with some idea.

Comment: Are you saying that you want this to be done on the server, renaming a file from what the user has committed from their working copy?

Comment: yes exactly I want this to be done in server

Answer (score 0):

Modifying in-flight transactions is a very bad idea with Subversion (or any other VCS for that matter). In doing so, you would be changing the intent and content of what the committer is attempting to commit to the repository. You also make the committer's working copy out of date *immediately*.

Not to mention failure cases. What happens if your modification is wrong? Makes an incorrect assumption? Breaks the build? Crashes mid-script?

Subversion *already* has a record of file contents at each revision and there is no need to keep that information in your file names in Subversion.

If you're intent on doing this (for what reason, I can't imagine), do it as part of your build/test/deploy process but **do not** commit those changes to the repository. If your development processes depend upon files being named in this way, those processes are likely broken - so you need to fix *that*, not muck around with filenames in Subversion.

Or, in your post-commit hook script, check out a working copy and rename all your files. Then recommit. But then you're going to invalidate your users' working copies on every commit, and get into an arms race over file names.

Answer (score 0):

Using subversion you only have server hooks. That means solving the [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) it can either accept or deny the svn-request.

What you can do is to refuse the commit on server side whenever the `test.js` has no versionnumber in its filename using a pre-commit-hook. Yes, this leave its responsibility to the committer, but as alroc said: Otherwise its invalidate the users copy.